# Powershell Cancel button Doesn't Call Function

Tags: powershell, checkbox, event-handling

I have script that creates pop-up with checkbox.

If checkbox is checked and OK is pressed, $districtArray[1] is True

BUT

If checkbox is checked and CANCEL is pressed, $districtArray[1] is ALSO True

I wish that CANCEL button will make entire $districtArray FALSE.

Hence I included function `initArray` when CANCEL is clicked

`$CancelButton.Add_Click({initArray; $Form.Close()})`

And here is entire script for reference

```
$i = $NULL
$districtArray = @()
$highestDistrict = 33




function initArray{
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $highestDistrict; $i++) 
    { 
       $script:districtArray += @($false) 
    }


}



function checkbox_test{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

    # Set the size of your form
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.width = 500
    $Form.height = 200
    $Form.Text = ”Select District”

    # Set the font of the text to be used within the form
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12)
    $Form.Font = $Font

    # create your checkbox 
    $checkbox1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $checkbox1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(30,30)
    $checkbox1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(250,50)
    $checkbox1.Text = "01"
    $checkbox1.Checked = $false
    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox1)  

    # Add an OK button
    $OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,100)
    $OKButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    #Add a cancel button
    $CancelButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(255,100)
    $CancelButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({initArray; $Form.Close()})
    $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    ###########  This is the important piece ##############
    #                                                     #
    # Do something when the state of the checkbox changes #
    #######################################################
    $checkbox1.Add_CheckStateChanged({
    if ($checkbox1.Checked){$districtArray[1] = $true} })


    # Activate the form
    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog() 
}



initArray

#Call the function
checkbox_test


write-host "Value of districtArray[1] is" $districtArray[1]
```

Comment: Your `initArray` adds 33 new `$false` elements into array. It does not turn any `$true` element to `$false`.

Comment: @PetSerAl But if I click "01" and then the Cancel button, then $districtArray[1] is set to True.

Comment: But you have `$districtArray.Length` equals to 66.